# Dictionary mapping return Nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

i have two data-set and i want to create a dictionary from two columns of Table A, then create a new column in Table B that perform like excel vloopup

Table A

```
Date       Wk of Year   ...Other columns
2020-1-1       1
2020-1-2       1
2020-1-10      2
2020-1-11      2
```

Table B

```
Shop   Date        Sales   ...Other columns
A      2020-1-1    100
B      2020-1-1    100
C      2020-1-1    100
A      2020-1-10   100

Expected Result
Shop   Date        Sales   Wk of Year
A      2020-1-1    100         1
B      2020-1-1    100         1
C      2020-1-1    100         1
A      2020-1-10   100         2
```

Code i create the dictionary from Table A

```
name = pd.to_datetime(Table A['date'])
wk =   Table A['Wk of Year']
dict= dict(zip(name,wk))

Table B['wk'] = pd.to_datetime(Table B ['Date'].map(dict)
```

Actual Result :

```
Shop   Date        Sales   Wk of Year
A      2020-1-1    100         NaT
B      2020-1-1    100         NaT
C      2020-1-1    100         Nat
A      2020-1-10   100         Nat
```

Comment: Firstly, don't use `dict` as a name in `dict= dict(zip(name,wk))` because you're trampling over the builtin name. Second, you can't just call `pd.to_datetime` on a column of integers; that's why you're getting `NaT`. Why are you using `pd.to_datetime` at all?

Comment: Can you modify your example so that it's valid code? A lot of that syntax is incorrect, and I can guarantee that `pd.to_datetime` will not return `NaT` and instead will throw an error, unless you specify `errors='coerce'`, which I don't see. It's difficult to provide a solution when the example doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the pandas `merge` function and pass the `on` arg - it is the column on what you want to join your datasets.

```
Table_merged = pd.merge(Table_B, Table_A['Date', 'Wk_of_Year'], on='Date')
```

It will create a dataset you expect:

```
         Date  Sales Shop  Wk_of_Year
0  2020-01-01    100    A           1
1  2020-01-01    100    B           1
2  2020-01-01    100    C           1
3  2020-01-10    100    D           2
```

But if you still want to use your strategy - use pandas `insert` function:

```
date_wk_dct = {key: value for key, value in Table_A[['Date', 'Wk_of_Year']].get_values()}
Table_B.insert(3, "Wk_of_Year", [date_wk_dct[v] for v in iter(Table_B['Date'].get_values())], True)
```

This will insert the new column in your existing Table_B dataset and the result will be the same:

```
         Date  Sales Shop  Wk_of_Year
0  2020-01-01    100    A           1
1  2020-01-01    100    B           1
2  2020-01-01    100    C           1
3  2020-01-10    100    D           2
```