# python map function returns NaN value while key is existed in the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have trouble converting values using `map` and `dictionary`

Although I checked a similar situation here ([Dictionary mapping return Nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369944/dictionary-mapping-return-nan)), I can't understand why it didn't work well.

I have two dataframes, one is the main dataframe and another one is for the dictionary.

```py
df1
#   Gene Name   Drug IDs
#0  GLS2        DB00130 
#1  GLS2        DB11118 
#2  F13A1       DB00130 
#3  NOS2        DB00997 
#4  NOS2        DB09237
#...

id_converter
#   DrugBank ID of Ligand   DrugName
#0  DB00001                 Lepirudin
#1  DB00002                 Cetuximab
#2  DB00003                 Dornase alfa
#...
```

I made `id_converter` to the dictionary as below:

```py
drugbank_mapping = dict(id_converter[['DrugBank ID of Ligand', 'DrugName']].values)
```

Then, I converted Drug IDs to DrugName, but it returned NaN while the keys are in the dictionary

```py
df1['Drug IDs_name'] = df1['Drug IDs'].map(drugbank_mapping)
df1
#   Gene Name   Drug IDs    Drug IDs_name
#0  GLS2        DB00130     L-Glutamine
#1  GLS2        DB11118     NaN
#2  F13A1       DB00130     L-Glutamine
#3  NOS2        DB00997     Doxorubicin
#4  NOS2        DB09237     NaN
#...

drugbank_mapping['DB11118']
#'Ammonia'

drugbank_mapping['DB09237']
#'Levamlodipine'
```

Moreover, I tried `pd.merge`, but it returned the same result removing the `NaN` values.

Can anyone give me an idea for this problem?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Use `drugbank_mapping = id_converter.set_index('DrugBank ID of Ligand')['DrugName']`

Comment: How working `df1['Drug IDs_name'] = df1['Drug IDs'].st.rstrip().map(drugbank_mapping)` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I solved the problem with the above comment, but your code also worked well. Thanks!